# Alarm won't stop ringing without killing the app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm trying to add an alarm to the app I'm working on, but for some stupid reason, once the alarm is ringing I can't switch that off without killing the app.

The alarm is activated by a ToggleButton. If it's on, the alarm will ring at the scheduled time, and when it's off, it won't...or at least, it's not supposed to.

Here's the OnClick code for the ToggleButton:

```
@OnClick(R.id.alarmToggle2)
protected void onAlarmToggleClicked(){
    if(alarmToggle.isChecked()){
        alarmTimeText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        alarmTimeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Switch on the alarm
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMinute);

        //It's now time to set off the alarm
        Log.d(TAG, "ALARM");
        alarmReceiverIntent = new Intent(RemindersActivity.instance(),
                AlarmReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), alarmId,
                alarmReceiverIntent, 0);
        //RTC means that the alarm won't be used if the device is asleep, RTC_WAKEUP means
        //that it will.
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcastIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcastIntent);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cancel alarm");
        alarmTimeText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        alarmManager.cancel(broadcastIntent);
        alarmText.setText("");
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the AlarmReceiver class's onReceive() method:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //this will update the UI with message
        RemindersActivity inst = RemindersActivity.instance();
        //Sets the content of AlarmText in RemindersFragment
        inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

        //this will sound the alarm tone
        //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
        //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've since come up with a solution: the Ringtone is now a static variable of the AlarmReceiver, and this is how I stop the alarm ringing:

```
if(!alarmToggle.isChecked()) {
    //Stop the alarm from ringing
    if(AlarmReceiver.ringtone.isPlaying())
        AlarmReceiver.ringtone.stop();
    alarmTimeText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    alarmManager.cancel(broadcastIntent);
    alarmText.setText("");
}
```